# Help with ZK component development

Tags: rich-internet-application, zk

I'm developing a simple component. My jar structure is:

```
br/netsoft/zkComponents/Tef.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
metainfo/zk/lang-addon.xml
web/js/br/netsoft/zkComponents.js
web/zkComponents/tef.dsp
```

**My dsp file is:**

```
<c:set var="self" value="${requestScope.arg.self}"/>
<span z.type="br.netsoft.zkComponents.Tef" id="${self.uuid}" ${self.outerAttrs}${self.innerAttrs}>
<applet archive="tef.jar" id="tefApplet" code="br.netsoft.applets.tef.TEFProxy" width="0px" height="0px" />
<span/>
```

**and the language-addon.xml is:**

```
<language-addon>
<addon-name>componentes</addon-name>
<language-name>xul/html</language-name> 
<component> 
<component-name>tef</component-name> 
<component-class>br.netsoft.zkComponents.Tef</component-class> 
<mold> 
<mold-name>default</mold-name> 
<mold-uri>~./zkComponents/tef.dsp</mold-uri> 
</mold> 
</component> 
</language-addon>
```

When i try to test this component, appears a pop-up showing :
" /js/br/netsoft/zkComponents.js not found"

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if in ZK 5 , you need widget class

or in 3 , you need to specify the javascript location